# cannot find symbol. Although I can't see anything wrong

Tags: java, colors, compilation

Help! It says it can't find the symbol of the following:

```
 * c.setBackground(Color.Gray);         

 * Admin.setForeground(Color.White);      

 * AdminPass.setForeground(Color.White);
```

Ok, so here's the program.

---

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import java.sql.*;

public class Login extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    JLabel Admin = new JLabel ("Username: ");
    JTextField txtAdmin = new JTextField(20);
    JLabel AdminPass = new JLabel ("Password: ");
    JPasswordField txtPass = new JPasswordField(20);
    JLabel RemarksLabel = new JLabel();
    JButton OK = new JButton ("OK");
    JButton Cancel = new JButton ("Cancel");

    Container c = getContentPane();

    public Login()
    {
        c.setLayout (null);
        c.setBackground(Color.Gray);
        c.add(Admin);
        Admin.setForeground(Color.White);
        c.add(txtAdmin);
        c.add(AdminPass);
        AdminPass.setForeground(Color.White);
        c.add(txtPass);
        c.add(RemarksLabel);
        c.add(OK);
        c.add(Cancel);

        Admin.setBounds(10,20,80,20);
        txtAdmin.setBounds(80,20,100,20);
        AdminPass.setBounds(10,45,80,20);
        txtPass.setBounds(80,45,100,20);
        OK.setBounds(70,70,55,20);
        Cancel.setBounds(125,70,55,20);
        txtPass.addActionListener(this);
        OK.addActionListener(this);
        Cancel.addActionListener(this);


    }
}
```

Comment: Where is Color being defined?

Comment: What says it can't find the symbol of what? I didn't know Java *had* symbols.

Comment: My guess is that by symbol it is referring to the Color class and the compiler cannot find it.

Comment: Nevermind. I already fixed it. Thanks though. :) Although why does it says "Login is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener" ?

Comment: It means that actionPerformed(ActionEvent) is an abstract method in ActionListener and you need to either implement that method in your Login class or mark the class as abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to compile it and I think the reason is, that you have to use **Color.GRAY** instead of *Color.Gray* ...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the character case. You cant use a mix of lower and upper case like `Color.White`. It should be either `Color.white` (all in lowercase) or `Color.WHITE` (all in uppercase)

However if you are using all uppercase like `Color.WHITE`  and still showing error you should probably check your java compiler version or compliance level.

The uppercase `Color.WHITE` was added since java 1.4 if you are using a prior version it wont recognise. use `Color.white`.